# resnet50 theory question - output shape and dense layers units?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

i am learning tensorflow/keras for image classification and i feel like i'm missing a critical part of the theory.

the task that i am currently working on deals with using a pretrained model (Resnet50 in this case) to do classification on a small data set, with limited training time.

the data set is 1600 150 x 150 color photos of fruit, that fall into 12 classes. i am using a generator for the images:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        validation_split=0.25, 
        rescale=1/255,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rotation_range=90)
 
    train_datagen_flow = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/datasets/fruits_small/',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='sparse',
        subset='training',
        seed=12345)
 
    val_datagen_flow = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/datasets/fruits_small/',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='sparse',
        subset='validation',
        seed=12345)
 
    features, target = next(train_datagen_flow)
```

here is the layers i am using:

backbone = ResNet50(input_shape=(150, 150, 3),weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
backbone.trainable = False

```
model = Sequential()
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.add(backbone)
    model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Dense(2048,activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(512,activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(12, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
```

Now, this is my first attempt at using globalmax and resnet50, and i am experiencing MASSIVE overfitting, because, i presume, the small data set.

i've done some reading on the subject, and, i've tried a few normalization efforts with limited success.

in conversation with my tutor, he suggested that i think more critically about the output of the resnet model when selecting my parameters for my dense layers.

this comment made me realize that i have basically been arbitrarily selecting the filters for the dense layers, but it sounds like i should understand something related to the output of the previous layer when building a new one, and i'm not sure what, but i feel like i am missing something critical.

this is what my current layer summary looks like:

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
resnet50 (Model)             (None, 5, 5, 2048)        23587712  
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling2d_3 (Glob (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 2048)              4196352   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 2048)              8192      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 512)               1049088   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 12)                6156      
=================================================================
Total params: 28,849,548
Trainable params: 5,256,716
Non-trainable params: 23,592,832
```

here is what my current output looks like:

```
    Epoch 1/3
40/40 [==============================] - 363s 9s/step - loss: 0.5553 - acc: 0.8373 - val_loss: 3.8422 - val_acc: 0.1295
Epoch 2/3
40/40 [==============================] - 354s 9s/step - loss: 0.1621 - acc: 0.9423 - val_loss: 6.3961 - val_acc: 0.1295
Epoch 3/3
40/40 [==============================] - 357s 9s/step - loss: 0.1028 - acc: 0.9716 - val_loss: 4.8895 - val_acc: 0.1295
```

so i've read about freezing the resnet layers for training to help with overfitting, and regularization (*which is what i am attempting with the batch normalization? - though this seems to be considered questionable to a lot of people..*) i've also tried using dropout for the first and second dense layers as well as by increasing the data set size with augmentation (*i've got rotations and such*)

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Can be that is has something to do with the `class_mode='sparse',` passed to `datagen.flow_from_directory`. The output of the model is a softmax, right? It seems to me that corresponds better to `class_mode='"categorical"`.

Comment: Good observation, i can try that! :)

Comment: Turns out going categorical does OHE and it spirals out of control for resources very quickly and kills the kernel (looks like, anyhow)

Comment: Yes, the docs indeed say "Default: "categorical". Determines the type of label arrays that are returned: - "categorical" will be 2D one-hot encoded labels". Correct me if I am wrong, but a softmax is a OHE approximation, right? Not sure what you mean by spiralling out of control for resources, but you might want to slim down your dense layers. I think 5M trainable parameters is quite a lot to start with. What happens if you cut both layers in half?

Comment: @GillesOttervanger the kernel dies is what i meant by resources. i'm using an online platform for this (it is a course i am taking)

However, your suggestions of halving the layers was great - I was misunderstanding and thinking i needed to have a neuron for each output from the resnet, but, going with 256, then 64 to the final layer of 12 improved performance significantly

Answer (score 1):

So, i found that i had a misunderstanding about the shape of the output from the resnet/global average layer - it had a shape of 2048, and i was thinking that meant i needed my first dense layer to have 2048 filters, which was causing significant overfitting issues.

i ultimately changed my dense layers to have 256, then 64 and finally 12 (because i have 12 classes to categorize) and that significantly improved performance.